# c++ do while infinity loop

Tags: c++, loops, infinity

When I try to use do while, my program below will fall into infinity loop if I input a character at second round.
I don't know why, could you explain it to me?

I ran it on

> Visual studio version 11.0.61219.00 update 5

```
//============================================================
//Do while infinity loop
//============================================================
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{   
    int n;
    do{
        cout << "#####Enter the number you need check#####" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        if  (n != 0 && n <= 10) 
        cout << "You entered  " << n <<  endl;
        cout << "Enter 0 if you want to exit loop" << endl;
        if (n > 10)
        {
            cout << "Sorry with the number " << n << " the result is too big that why i can show you"  << endl; 
        }
    }
    while( n != 0); // do chi check n khac' 0 nen khi da chay 1 vong` do while luc này n da duoc gan' gia tri tu` vong` lap truoc -> vong` sau input sai gia tri vi' du character 'y' -> code se khong input duoc gia tri moi' vao ->dung` gia tri cu -> infinity
    {
        cout << "You entered number 0 then bye" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;   
}
```

Input

```
10
y
```

Output

```
10                                                                                                                                
You entered  10                                                                                                                   
Enter 0 if you want to exit loop                                                                                                  
#####Enter the number you need check#####                                                                                         
y                                                                                                                                 
You entered  10                                                                                                                   
Enter 0 if you want to exit loop
#####Enter the number you need check##### 
10                                                                                                                                
You entered  10                                                                                                                   
Enter 0 if you want to exit loop                                                                                                  
#####Enter the number you need check##### 
10                                                                                                                                
You entered  10                                                                                                                   
Enter 0 if you want to exit loop                                                                                                  
#####Enter the number you need check#####
```

Comment: Infinite loop? What happens if you then input a 0?

Comment: your loop is set up to exit only when the input is `0`, you never input a `0`, so it never exits. If you input a `0`, I would expect it to exit fine.

Comment: `while( n != 0);` you have a trialing semi colon there which you p[robably didn't mean

Comment: @MikeVine - it's a `do ... while`. So that's okay.

Comment: Hi i ran it on Visual studio version 11.0.61219.00 update 5 and after input value 10 then input character 'y' -> it will fall to infinity loop, and i just dont know why :(

Comment: You need to check if the `>>` operator succeeded. Because when it fails `n` isn't updated. Try adding `if (cin >> n) break;`

Comment: @MikeVine he almost certainly did mean to put those, as leaving them off would be a syntax error. The more confusing parts are the superfluous brackets around the final cout.

Comment: @rustyx I tried run above code via this site "https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler" then it's ok  but via my visual studio then is not :( Could you fix it and explain to me :( i know it maybe a stupid inquire :( i just a newbie T.T and my english suck :(  sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//============================================================
//Do while infinity loop
//============================================================




int main()
{
    int n;
    do {
        cout << "#####Enter the number you need check#####" << endl;

        cin >> n;
        if (!cin) // or if(cin.fail())
        {
        // user didn't input a number
            cin.clear(); // reset failbit
            cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //skip bad input
                                                                       // next, request user reinput
        }else {

            if (n != 0 && n <= 10) {
                cout << "You entered  " << n << endl;
            }

            if (n > 10)
            {
                cout << "Sorry with the number " << n << " the result is too big that why i can show you" << endl;
            }

            cout << "Enter 0 if you want to exit loop" << endl;// day la mot dong cac ban da comment bang tieng viet

        }
    }while(n != 0);

    {
        cout << "You entered number 0 then bye" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Try it.

I do not know exactly what your error is. It's probably because you tried to assign a non-int variable to an int leading to a memory overflow. So, check the input number before performing other tasks

Comment: Thank you . That's helpful  . My problem is "i ran above code on my  Visual studio version 11.0.61219.00 update 5 and after input value 10 then input character 'y' -> it will fall to infinity loop but if i try it via this site https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler then it's not although it's same source code :( The result is too different That why it's make me confusing :)

Comment: I tried your code with VS Studio version 15.7.27703.2035 and also encountered the same error. I think your online site has used an old compile version. So, you should update some more effective solution. Good luck